# git hook to warn if changelog not updated?

Tags: git, githooks

How can I write a git hook that outputs a warning in the comment section if there have been no commits to CHANGELOG on the current branch ?

I would like to output something like:

```
# CHANGELOG Not updated.
#
# Update changelog before submitting PR.
#
```

Comment: Should it warn on each commit, or only on a push?

Comment: On the current branch? Or the current commit? Maybe use run a git diff of the file from HEAD to the merge base?

Answer (score 6):

If you want a local commit hook, you can add this script under `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/bash
if git status -s | grep -q "M CHANGELOG"; then
    exit 0
else
    echo "# CHANGELOG Not updated."
    exit 1
fi
```

Please notice that commit hooks are not versioned nor included in the repository

Comment: Thanks for the note on how they are not included in the repo, I've made a script to install the hooks.